# Print problem after scanning random String

Tags: java

my code does not print the if and else if methods after the random String from the array is scanned.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class ScherreSteinPapier {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        String Pos[] = {"Schere", "Stein", "Papier"};
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        String eingabe = scanner.nextLine();
        //if (String.valueOf(login).equals("accnumber"))
        Random random = new Random();
        
        int zufall=random.nextInt(Pos.length);
        System.out.println(Pos[zufall]);
    
            if (eingabe.equals(String.valueOf(zufall))) {
                System.out.println("Gleichstand");
        }
        else if (eingabe.equals(Pos[0]) && String.valueOf(zufall).equals(Pos[1])) {
            System.out.println("Verloren");
        }
        else if (eingabe.equals(Pos[0]) && (String.valueOf(zufall).equals(Pos[2]))) {
            System.out.println("Gewonnen");
        
        }
        else if (eingabe.equals(Pos[1]) && (String.valueOf(zufall).equals(Pos[0]))) {
            System.out.println("Gewonnen");
        }
        else if (eingabe.equals(Pos[1]) && (String.valueOf(zufall).equals(Pos[0]))) {
            System.out.println("Verloren");
        }
        else if (eingabe.equals(Pos[2]) && (String.valueOf(zufall).equals(Pos[1]))) {
            System.out.println("Gewonnen");
        }
        else if (eingabe.equals(Pos[2]) && (String.valueOf(zufall).equals(Pos[0]))) {
            System.out.println("Verloren");
        }
        else if (!eingabe.equals(Pos[0]) && (!eingabe.equals(Pos[1]) && (!eingabe.equals(Pos[2])))) {
            System.out.println("Fehler");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're converting a number into a string and comparing it to strings that have letters. The conditions shouldn't pass.

Comment: Instead of `String.valueOf(zufall)` I think it should be: `Pos[zufall]`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hey thank you! The code works perfectly now.